# how to print values from file after appending

Tags: c, file, struct, scanf

I have the following problem: I must must make a student file with name, age and grades. It works ok, but the problem is when printing everything on the screen. Let's say I read 3 students, when I type 'L' for printing the content on screen it works great. When I press 'A' to add another student to the file(append), the student will appear in my file(so we have a total of 4 students), but when I press 'L' to print again, it just prints 3 out of 4 students, including the appended one, but removes anther one. 'S' stands for write the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct student{
    char nume[20];
    int varsta;
    float medie;
};

void citire_date(struct student *studenti, FILE *f, int n){
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Introduceti datele studentului %d\n", i+1);
        printf("Nume: "); fflush(stdin); gets((studenti+i)->nume);
        printf("Varsta: "); scanf("%d", &((studenti+i)->varsta));
        printf("Medie: "); scanf("%f", &((studenti+i)->medie));
        fprintf(f, "Nume: %s\n", (studenti+i)->nume);
        fprintf(f, "Varsta: %d\n", (studenti+i)->varsta);
        fprintf(f, "Medie: %.2f\n", (studenti+i)->medie);
        fprintf(f, "\n");
    }
}

void afisare_date(struct student *studenti, int n){
    int i;
    char nume1;
    int varsta1;
    float medie1;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
       printf("Nume: %s\n", (studenti+i)->nume);
        printf("Varsta: %d\n", (studenti+i)->varsta);
        printf("Medie: %.2f\n", (studenti+i)->medie);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void append(struct student *studenti, FILE *f){
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<1;i++){
        printf("Nume: "); fflush(stdin); gets((studenti+i)->nume);
        printf("Varsta: "); scanf("%d", &((studenti+i)->varsta));
        printf("Medie: "); scanf("%f", &((studenti+i)->medie));
        fprintf(f, "Nume: %s\n", (studenti+i)->nume);
        fprintf(f, "Varsta: %d\n", (studenti+i)->varsta);
        fprintf(f, "Medie: %.2f\n", (studenti+i)->medie);
        fprintf(f, "\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    struct student studenti[20];
    int n;
    char optiune;

    f=fopen("studenti.txt", "w");
    if(f==NULL){
        printf("Nu s-a putut deschide/crea fisierul pentru scriere.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\n");

    do{
        printf("S. Scriere fisier.\n");
        printf("A. Adaugarea unui nou student in fisier.\n");
        printf("L. Listarea datelor tuturor studentilor.\n");
        printf("M. Modificarea datelor unui student.\n");
        printf("C. Cautarea unui student dupa nume.\n");
        printf("X. Terminarea programului.\n");
        printf("Introduceti optiunea: "); fflush(stdin); optiune=toupper(getchar());
        printf("\n");


        switch(optiune){
            case 'S':
                printf("Introduceti numarul de studenti: "); scanf("%d", &n);
                citire_date(studenti, f, n);
                fclose(f);
                printf("\n");
                break;
            case 'A':
                f = fopen("studenti.txt", "a");
                if(f==NULL ){
                    printf("Nu s-a putut deschide fisierul pentru adaugare.\n");
                    exit(2);
                }
                append(studenti, f);
                fclose(f);
                break;
            case 'L':
                afisare_date(studenti, n);
                break;
            case 'M':
                break;
            case 'C':
                break;
            case 'X':
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nAti introdus o optiune eronata!\n");
                break;

        }
    }while(optiune!='X');





    return 0;
}
```

I think I need to use fscanf, but I do not know how becasue it will read from file that "Nume: name" "Varsta: 19" and so on.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try running the code inside a debugger?

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is **Undefined Behavior**. Always. Also, do not use `gets` it is no longer part of the C standard due to being horribly insecure. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: `f = fopen("studenti.txt", "a");` but the file was already opened with `f` earlier. Don't do that: use `fseek()` to position the file pointer before listing and before appending.

Comment: If I don't use 'fflush(stdin):' it jumps from 'Nume' to 'Varsta' without letting me typing the name.

Comment: `case 'S'` that is where I close my file.

Comment: You have a mix of styles due to trying to keep the file open. For each function: open, operate, close.

Comment: The file is closed after the first function `fclose(f)`. I am only using one function at a time.

Comment: You have destroyed the previous file with the first `fopen("studenti.txt", "w");` so for each function: open, operate, close.

Comment: I did not destroyed anything, writing works great, appending works great, just listing does not work great. My file contains everything I need, just I can't print it on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my main, so everything should be clear to see now.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    struct student studenti[20];
    int n;
    char optiune;

     printf("Introduceti numarul de studenti: "); scanf("%d", &n);

    f=fopen("studenti.txt", "w");
    if(f==NULL){
        printf("Nu s-a putut deschide/crea fisierul pentru scriere.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    citire_date(studenti, f, n);
    fclose(f);

    printf("\n");

    do{
        printf("A. Adaugarea unui nou student in fisier.\n");
        printf("L. Listarea datelor tuturor studentilor.\n");
        printf("M. Modificarea datelor unui student.\n");
        printf("C. Cautarea unui student dupa nume.\n");
        printf("X. Terminarea programului.\n");
        printf("Introduceti optiunea: "); fflush(stdin); optiune=toupper(getchar());
        printf("\n");


        switch(optiune){
            case 'A':
                f = fopen("studenti.txt", "a");
                if(f==NULL ){
                    printf("Nu s-a putut deschide fisierul pentru adaugare.\n");
                    exit(2);
                }
                append(studenti, f);
                fclose(f);
                break;
            case 'L':
                afisare_date(studenti, n);
                break;
            case 'M':
                break;
            case 'C':
                break;
            case 'X':
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nAti introdus o optiune eronata!\n");
                break;

        }
    }while(optiune!='X');





    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions now ?

Answer (score 0):

In `append()` the loop

```
for(i=0;i<1;i++) {
    ...
    gets((studenti+i)->nume);
```

writes to `studenti[0]`

It appends to the file but not to the array. The function needs to know (and return) the number of students you already have.

```
int append(struct student *studenti, FILE *f, int studs){
    int i;

    printf("Nume: "); fflush(stdin); gets((studenti+studs)->nume);
    printf("Varsta: "); scanf("%d", &((studenti+studs)->varsta));
    printf("Medie: "); scanf("%f", &((studenti+studs)->medie));
    fprintf(f, "Nume: %s\n", (studenti+studs)->nume);
    fprintf(f, "Varsta: %d\n", (studenti+studs)->varsta);
    fprintf(f, "Medie: %.2f\n", (studenti+studs)->medie);
    fprintf(f, "\n");
    return studs + 1;
}
```

Comment: @OlarAndrei added to my answer because the `append()` function overwrites the first array element.

Comment: Ok, I added 2 students, then appended one more, so there should be 3, but when I'm printing it just prints me the first 2, the one appended won't get printed on the screen.

Comment: Look after the total number of students.

Comment: Well, I still don't get how :)

Comment: Keep a variable `int totalstudents`. When you add a record, increment it. When you print the list, use it. But don't use the identifier `n`. Only use such a short identifier in a very local and obvious situation, because `n` has no meaning implied.

Comment: Ok, I've managed to print everything all right. I have one more question, how can I search for a specific name in the file, and once I found it to modify something(name, age or grade), ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code was not far off. The primary issue was your handling of input, and in appending students. First a few critical issues:

`fflush(stdin)` is **Undefined Behavior** and is always wrong. Never use `gets` it is no longer part of libc and unsecure.

You can handle input of single strings with `scanf` fairly well with the format string `"%[^\n]%*c"`. This will consume the trailing `newline` and empty `stdin`. (it isn't foolproof, but it works for most purposes). It also provides a way for you to check the return for an empty-string (e.g. `[Enter]` alone) and terminate input (see below). For reading numbers (e.g. `int`, `float`, ...) you are responsible for emptying `stdin` before calling `scanf` again. I created a simple `flush_stdin()` function to do this for you below.

Lastly, `append` needs to take the current student count and increment that within the function. Passing a pointer to `n` is the easiest way to approach this. It also allows you to read multiple students in `append` and simply hit `[Enter]` on the blank line for `(studenti + *n)->nume)` to terminate input. (you should also `#define MAXSTUDENTS 20` (your current, or whatever you need) so that you can check you don't exceed the number of students when appending. (e.g. `if (*n == MAXSTUDENTS)` and take proper action)

Below is an updated version of your code that works closer to the way your intended. Look over the code and let me know if you have questions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void flush_stdin () 
{
    int c = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

struct student{
    char nume[20];
    int varsta;
    float medie;
};

void citire_date(struct student *studenti, FILE *f, size_t n)
{
    int i = 0;  /* always initialize ALL variables */

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Introduceti datele studentului %d\n", i+1);
        printf("  Nume: "); scanf ( "%[^\n]%*c", (studenti+i)->nume);
        printf("  Varsta: "); scanf("%d", &((studenti+i)->varsta));
    flush_stdin ();
        printf("  Medie: "); scanf("%f", &((studenti+i)->medie));
    flush_stdin ();
        fprintf(f, "Nume: %s\n", (studenti+i)->nume);
        fprintf(f, "Varsta: %d\n", (studenti+i)->varsta);
        fprintf(f, "Medie: %.2f\n", (studenti+i)->medie);
        fprintf(f, "\n");
    }
}

void afisare_date(struct student *studenti, size_t n)
{
    int i = 0;
//     char nume1 = 0;     /* what are these for? */
//     int varsta1 = 0;
//     float medie1 = 0.0;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Nume: %s\n", (studenti+i)->nume);
        printf("Varsta: %d\n", (studenti+i)->varsta);
        printf("Medie: %.2f\n", (studenti+i)->medie);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void append(struct student *studenti, FILE *f, size_t *n)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        printf ("\nEnter student information ([Enter] when done)\n\n");
        printf("  Nume: "); 
        if (!scanf ( "%[^\n]%*c", (studenti + *n)->nume))
        {
            flush_stdin ();
            break;
        }
        printf("  Varsta: "); scanf("%d", &((studenti + *n)->varsta));
        if ((studenti+i)->varsta == '\n')
            break;
    flush_stdin ();
        printf("  Medie: "); scanf("%f", &((studenti + *n)->medie));
        if ((studenti+i)->medie == '\n')
            break;
    flush_stdin ();

        fprintf(f, "Nume: %s\n", (studenti + *n)->nume);
        fprintf(f, "Varsta: %d\n", (studenti + *n)->varsta);
        fprintf(f, "Medie: %.2f\n", (studenti + *n)->medie);
        fprintf(f, "\n");

        (*n)++;  /* increment numbre of students */
    }
}

int main()
{
    FILE *f = NULL;
    struct student studenti[20];
    size_t n = 0;
    char optiune = 0;

    f=fopen("studenti.txt", "w");
    if(f==NULL){
        printf("Nu s-a putut deschide/crea fisierul pentru scriere.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\n");

    do{
        printf("S. Scriere fisier.\n");
        printf("A. Adaugarea unui nou student in fisier.\n");
        printf("L. Listarea datelor tuturor studentilor.\n");
        printf("M. Modificarea datelor unui student.\n");
        printf("C. Cautarea unui student dupa nume.\n");
        printf("X. Terminarea programului.\n");
        printf("Introduceti optiunea: "); 
        optiune=toupper(getchar());
        flush_stdin(); 
        printf("\n");


        switch(optiune){
            case 'S':
                printf("Introduceti numarul de studenti: "); scanf("%d", &n);
            flush_stdin ();
                citire_date(studenti, f, n);
                fclose(f);
                printf("\n");
                break;
            case 'A':
                f = fopen("studenti.txt", "a");
                if(f==NULL ){
                    printf("Nu s-a putut deschide fisierul pentru adaugare.\n");
                    exit(2);
                }
                append(studenti, f, &n);
                fclose(f);
                break;
            case 'L':
                afisare_date(studenti, n);
                break;
            case 'M':
                break;
            case 'C':
                break;
            case 'X':
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nAti introdus o optiune eronata!\n");
                break;

        }
    }while(optiune!='X');


    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/student_missing

S. Scriere fisier.
A. Adaugarea unui nou student in fisier.
L. Listarea datelor tuturor studentilor.
M. Modificarea datelor unui student.
C. Cautarea unui student dupa nume.
X. Terminarea programului.
Introduceti optiunea: s

Introduceti numarul de studenti: 1
Introduceti datele studentului 1
  Nume: John Student
  Varsta: 1
  Medie: 91.2

S. Scriere fisier.
A. Adaugarea unui nou student in fisier.
L. Listarea datelor tuturor studentilor.
M. Modificarea datelor unui student.
C. Cautarea unui student dupa nume.
X. Terminarea programului.
Introduceti optiunea: l

Nume: John Student
Varsta: 1
Medie: 91.20

S. Scriere fisier.
A. Adaugarea unui nou student in fisier.
L. Listarea datelor tuturor studentilor.
M. Modificarea datelor unui student.
C. Cautarea unui student dupa nume.
X. Terminarea programului.
Introduceti optiunea: a


Enter student information ([Enter] when done)

  Nume: Jill Student
  Varsta: 2
  Medie: 94.3

Enter student information ([Enter] when done)

  Nume: Juan Student
  Varsta: 3
  Medie: 92.5

Enter student information ([Enter] when done)

  Nume:
S. Scriere fisier.
A. Adaugarea unui nou student in fisier.
L. Listarea datelor tuturor studentilor.
M. Modificarea datelor unui student.
C. Cautarea unui student dupa nume.
X. Terminarea programului.
Introduceti optiunea: l

Nume: John Student
Varsta: 1
Medie: 91.20

Nume: Jill Student
Varsta: 2
Medie: 94.30

Nume: Juan Student
Varsta: 3
Medie: 92.50

S. Scriere fisier.
A. Adaugarea unui nou student in fisier.
L. Listarea datelor tuturor studentilor.
M. Modificarea datelor unui student.
C. Cautarea unui student dupa nume.
X. Terminarea programului.
Introduceti optiunea: x
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have managed to do this in another way, but i'll also do it this way.  I have one more question, how can I search for a specific name in the file, and once I found it to modify something(name, age or grade), ?

Comment: You will use either a `while` or `for` loop to iterate `i` through each student and `if (strcmp ((studenti+i)->nume), SearchName) == 0) strncpy ((studenti+i)->nume, NewName, strlen(NewName));` That's probably the easy way.

Comment: I've got to run. Just drop me a comment with any more questions and I'll get to them in a bit.